# Is the 16-bit math in this program invoking undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, msvc14

The other day I upgraded my Windows build environment from MSVC2013 to MSVC2017, and lo and behold, a function in my program that had been working fine for years (and still works fine under g++/clang) suddenly started giving incorrect results when compiled with MSVC2017.

I was able to rewrite the function to give correct results again, but the experience made me curious -- was my function invoking undefined behavior (that just happened to give correct results until now), or was the code well-defined and MSVC2017 was being buggy?

Below is a trivial program showing a toy version of the function both before and after I rewrote it.  In particular, does the function maybe_invokes_undefined_behavior(), as shown below, invoke undefined behavior, when called with an argument of value -32762?

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {ciFirstToken = -32768};

// This function sometimes gives unexpected results under MSVC2017
void maybe_invokes_undefined_behavior(short token)
{
   if (token >= 0) return;

   token -= ciFirstToken;  // does this invoke undefined behavior if (token==-32762) and (ciFirstToken==-32768)?
   if (token == 6)
   {
      printf("Token is 6, as expected (unexpected behavior not reproduced)\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Token should now be 6, but it's actually %i\n", (int) token);  // under MSVC2017 this prints -65530 !?
   }
}

// This function is rewritten to use int-math instead of short-math and always gives the expected result
void allgood(short token16)
{
   if (token16 >= 0) return;

   int token = token16;
   token -= ciFirstToken;
   if (token == 6)
   {
      printf("Token is 6, as expected (odd behavior not reproduced)\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Token should now be 6, but it's actually %i\n", (int) token);  
   }
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   maybe_invokes_undefined_behavior(-32762);
   allgood(-32762);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of VS2017 are you using?  I can't reproduce the problem with v15.7.3 (x86 or x64, using /Od or /Ox).

Comment: I'm using v15.7.3, IIRC.

Comment: What is `INT_MAX` on this system?

Comment: Also can you show the exact unedited output of the program in the alleged buggy instance?

Comment: Seeing as people cannot reproduce the problem it would be helpful to post the exact compiler version and compilation switches to reproduce

Comment: They key problem of course is that `-(-32768)` in short math overflows with Undefined Behavior. The MSVC bug seems to be that it's transforming the valid code above to another form, and accidentally introduces that UB.

Comment: The compiler prints its version on each invocation, should be something like 19.13.26129 (this version doesn't seem to reproduce the bug).

Comment: You really need to tell us the values of `SHORT_MIN` and `SHORT_MAX` on your platform for any determination of what's defined and what's not.  Without that information, the question is close to meaningless.

Comment: @TobySpeight: It's just MSVC++, so -32768/+32767

Comment: @MSalters, it should still be in the question, rather than assuming that everyone on SO knows (and can remember) the implementation-defined limits of every compiler/target combination.

Comment: If `ciFirstToken` was a 16-bit _unsigned_ and `short` was 32-bit, output `-65530` would make sense.

Comment: If `int` was 16-bit (2's complement) , then `enum {ciFirstToken = -32768};` would be a problem (UB) fixable with `enum {ciFirstToken = -32767 - 1};`.  Yet a 16-bit `int` is not likely with MSVC.  I am wondering if some setting was forcing `enum` to 16-bit or 16-bit unsigned?

Comment: Did the program output the "unexpected value" message with a value of 6, or did it show the message along with some other value?  I wonder if the compiler tried to get too clever and determine what value `token` would need to have to satisfy the `if`, and failed to account for wrapping in such computation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does this invoke undefined behavior if (token==-32762) and
>   (ciFirstToken==-32768)?
>
> `token -= ciFirstToken;`

NO (for the short answer)

Now let's break this down piece by piece.

**1) As per [expr.ass](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.ass-7) for compound assignment, `-=`:**

> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1` *op=* `E2` is equivalent to
>   `E1 = E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

the expression:

```
token -= ciFirstToken;
```

is equivalent to:

```
token = token - ciFirstToken;
//            ^ binary (not unary)
```

**2) The [additive operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#add-1) (`-`) performs [*usual arithmetic conversion*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5) for operands of arithmetic type.**

As per [expr.arith.conv/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1)

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the **usual arithmetic conversions**,
>   which are defined as follows:
>   (1.5) Otherwise, the **integral promotions shall be performed on both operands**.

**3) Both operands are then promoted to an `int`.**

As per [conv.prom/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#1):

> A *prvalue* of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_­`t, `char32_­t`, or
>   wchar_­t whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of `int`
>   can be converted to a *prvalue* of type `int` if `int` can represent all the
>   values of the source type;

**4) After the integer promotion, no further conversion is required.**

As per [expr.arith.conv/1.5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5.1)

> If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.

**5) Finally, *Undefined behavior* for expressions is defined as per [expr.pre](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#pre-4):**

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or **not in the range** of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is *undefined*

---

**CONCLUSION**

So now substituting the values:

```
token = -32762 - (-32768);
```

After all the integer promotions, both operands fall within the valid range of **INT_MIN**<sup>[1]</sup> and **INT_MAX**<sup>[2]</sup>.

And after evaluation, the mathematical result (6) is then *implicitly* converted to `short`, which is within the valid range of `short`.

Thus, expression is *well-formed*.

Many thanks to @MSalters, @n.m and @Arne Vogel for helping with this answer.

---

Visual Studio 2015 MSVC14 [Integer Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx) and [MS Integer Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits) defines:

<sup>[1]</sup> INT_MIN    -2147483648
<sup>[2]</sup> INT_MAX   +2147483647

SHRT_MIN    –32768
SHRT_MAX   +32767

Comment: "Visual Studio 2015 MSVC14 Integer Limits" are nice, yet it is the 2017 one's that may explain the issue - although I doubt it.

Comment: @chux, this is the MS reference for [integer limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits). Most likely nothing has changed since the standard hasn't too.

Comment: @chux Microsoft are the kings of backwards compatibility - they're the ones who kept `long` as 32 bits instead of moving to 64 bits like everyone else. The chances that they'd change those limits is nil.

Comment: @MarkRansom: What advantage are they foregoing by interpreting `long` as "the smallest size that's at least 32 bits"?  Is there any reason that code that actually *wants* 64 bits shouldn't use `int64_t` or `long long`?

Comment: @supercat I wasn't criticizing their choice at all, just using it as evidence of their priorities.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Fair point.  I wonder what other priorities drive different behaviors?  IMHO, quality implementations for 64-bit platforms should offer a choice of whether "long" should be treated as 32 or 64 bits, just as quality implementations for the 68000 allowed "int" to be 16 or 32 bits.  The 16/32-bit int selection was complicated by the fact that the choice affects how "int" values get passed on the stack--an issue which would not be a problem on most 64-bit platforms which pass 32-bit and 64-bit values in compatible fashion.